# PHP Symfony redirection

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have taken a new job and the codes are a little complex. I'm looking for a page to edit. The older programmer used PHP Symfony framework with no comment tags.

My question is:

Pages are loaded by GET request like that: www.asd.com/asd.php/manage

I just can't find where is file and where 'manage' loads from.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to ask that other developer.

Comment: Or start with symfony manual.

Comment: You should post a bit of the controller code and the routes. This is a little bit of a too vague and broad question, certainly without context. Just as @u_mulder says, a tutorial would be a good entry point. Look for the html/view folder in the project.

Comment: Start with the index file (could be index.php) and follow the code...

Comment: Come on meeeen. I know all this things. I just asked is there any file that include redirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is to look into the routing. It can be defined using annotations or a seperate routes file (maybe there are other options but this seem to be the most common ones). Here is the documentation of the symfony routing https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

If you are not getting to the right point you can use the router debug `php bin/console debug:router`. This lists all routes of the application. If you want to know which controller is used for a specific route you can use the `debug:router <route_key>` for a specific route, resulting in more information:

```
$ php bin/console debug:router fos_user_security_login
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                     |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | fos_user_security_login                                   |
| Path         | /login                                                    |
| Path Regex   | #^/login$#sD                                              |
| Host         | ANY                                                       |
| Host Regex   |                                                           |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                       |
| Method       | GET|POST                                                  |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                 |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                           |
| Defaults     | _controller: fos_user.security.controller:loginAction     |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler   |
| Callable     | FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```